# What is design pattern to store JSON objects in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

A co-worker and I have been discussed the best way to store data in memory within our C++ server. Basically, we need to store all requisitions made by clients. Those requisitions come as JSONs objects, so each requisition may have different number of parameters. Later, clients can ask the server for a list of those requisitions.

The total number of requisitions is small (order of 10^3). Clients ask for the list of requisitions using pagination.

So my question is what is the standard way of doing that?

1) Create a class that stores every JSON and then, when requested, send the list of those JSONs.

2) Deserialize the JSON, store it in a class then serialize the data again when requested.

If 2, what is the best way of doing that in modern C++?

3) Another option?

Thank you.

Comment: From your explanation it sounds like you never need to interpret the JSON. If that's the case, why would you deserialize it?

Comment: Why constrain this to C++? Why not use NodeJS? IMHO, don't use C++ to solve this problem when other technologies would get you there faster and with greater simplicity.

Comment: With all those requirements, there's very little code you have to show for your effors.

Comment: @Darhuuk you are right, I did not write the whole story. We did interpret the JSON for other software's functionalities. Now we also need to store those JSONs and send it back to clients when requested.

Comment: @keith thank you for your answer. We already have a server in C++ that does other things with those JSONs. We use NodeJS for other services though.

Comment: That does still not answer the question of Darhuuk. The JSON you receive should/will that be always send unmodified back to the client - if so why is there a need to store it as anything else then a string? - if you modify it in any way (e.g. adding/removing properties or changing their value)  and send that modified JSON back then the question is too vague.

Comment: @Giordano, I'm not convinced! Microservices?

Answer (score 1):

If the client asks you to support JSON, the are only two steps you need to do:

1. Add some JSON (e.g [this](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)) library with a suitable license to project.
2. Use it.

If the implementation of JSON is not the main goal of the project, this should work.

Note: you can also get a lot of design hints inspecting the aforementioned repo.